# Change gnome lockscreen clock font

Tags: 16.04, gnome, screensaver

Is there a way to change the font and size of the clock in the Gnome lockscreen?

I've done research and did not find any corresponding configuration file. The font setting in `gnome-tweak-tool` doesn't seem to affect the font used in the lockscreen.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Gnome 3.20.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426383/179547) from Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

> Not sure if this is a little too late but you can customize the values in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` and that does the trick. Just find the `screen-shield-clock` class and make your changes.

If this doesn't work try tweaking `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` file.

ps. Do not forget to backup files before changes!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gdm3setup](https://github.com/Nano77/gdm3setup). It has an option for changing the font. However, it has not been developed for a few years so ~your milage may vary~.